# Excel formula to extract a number preceding an x not working

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, extract

I'm using the following formula to extract the number preceding an "x" from a string (e.g. ##x## where # equals a number 0-9) but with I have other words in the string that have an "x" in them, the formula doesn't work.

Here's the formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A154),"",IFERROR(IF(VALUE(MID(A154,MIN(FIND({"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"},A154 & "(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0")),FIND(INDEX(SET_TERMS,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A154,"*"&$R$2:$R$5&"*"),0)),A154,1)-MIN(FIND({"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"},A154 & "(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0"))))<=1,"",TRIM(MID(A154,MIN(FIND({"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"},A154 & "(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0")),FIND(INDEX(SET_TERMS,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A154,"*"&$R$2:$R$5&"*"),0)),A154,1)-MIN(FIND({"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"},A154 & "(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0")))&" sets")),""))
```

Notes: SET_TERMS ($R$2:$R$5) is a list: rounds, set, sets, x.

Here are examples where the formula works fine:

```
Skater jumps 3x5 each side  RESULT 3 sets
Russian Twist 3x30 seconds  RESULT 3 sets
Push-ups 3x max   RESULT 3 sets
Y holds 3x30 seconds   RESULT 3 sets
```

Now, here are two examples of the strings that return a blank because Flexion and Extension have "x" in them:

```
Neck Flexion 3x20 seconds  RESULT Blank
Neck Extension 3x20 seconds Result Blank
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: are the only numbers, or at least the first numbers those you want?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to be more specific in what you are looking for.

For example, the following will return the digit prior to the `x`:

```
=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9}&"x",A1&"0x1x2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9x")),1)
```

If you have Windows Excel 2013+ or O365, and you need to deal with multiple digit numbers, the following will extract space-separated "nodes" that have the pattern of `ddx`, where `dd` can be any number (including decimals). You can then use string functions to extract just the number.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[boolean(number(substring-before(.,'x')))]")
```

Comment: My list includes "x" as well as "rounds, set, sets" This formula only works for 3x10 but not for 3 sets 10. If you follow me.

Comment: @MikeElia I'm not surprised. Your title mentioned to *`extract a number preceding an  x`*. And your data examples only showed sequence with a number preceding an `x` That is very different from a number preceding a *`<space>rounds`* sequence, in part because of the intervening space. Please edit your question to provide a more comprehensive data input set (and desired Results) than restricting it just to the `x`.

Comment: @MikeElia  Also, in your present data example, is the part of the string that starts with `RESULT` also part of the original string?  Or is it showing what you want for a result? I ask because it is followed by `sets` and that is in your list.  In which case you would have two extractions to do.